# angularjs - ng-view re-arranges html elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to learn angular, and am building a small application. The problem is that when I click on an `ng-view`, my original css gets messed up.

I would like all the elements to stay in their current position when a new view is rendered.

I created a plunker here

http://plnkr.co/edit/re40GAAB8NYFdrGBSTlk?p=preview

**app.js**

```
angular.module("fitbird", ['ngRoute'])
    .controller("HomeCtrl", function($scope) {
        $scope.number = 1;
    })
    .controller('UserRegistrationsCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    }])
    .controller('UserSessionsCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    }])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'views/welcome/index.html.erb',
                controller: 'HomeCtrl'
            })
            .when('/sign_in', {
                templateUrl: 'templates/user_sessions/new.html',
                controller: 'UserSessionsCtrl'
            })
            .when('/sign_up', {
                templateUrl: 'templates/user_registrations/new.html',
                controller: 'UserRegistrationsCtrl'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
    }]);
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular-route.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>

<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">
  <ul class="list-inline" ng-app="my-app" ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
    <li><a href="#sign_in">Sign In</a></li>
    <li><a href="#sign_up">Sign Up</a></li>
    <div ng-view=""></div>
    <li>Help</li>
    <li>{{5+5}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**signin.html**

```
<div class="login-form">
    <form ng-submit="submitLogin(loginForm)" role="form" ng-init="loginForm = {}">
        <button class="btn btn-primary fb-btn">Log in with Facebook</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger google-btn">Log in up with Google+</button>
        <h4 class="text-center">Or</h4>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Password">
        <a href="password" class="forgot-password">Forgot Password?</a>
        <button class="btn btn-danger login-btn">Log in</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

I have my four headings as follows

```
Sign In  Sign Up  Help 10
```

When I click on a view, help and 10 get rendered below the view.

Help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Umm..

Put:

```
<li>Help</li>
<li>{{5+5}}</li>
```

before the ng-view like so:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">
  <ul class="list-inline" ng-app="my-app" ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
    <li><a href="#sign_in">Sign In</a></li>
    <li><a href="#sign_up">Sign Up</a></li>
    <li>Help</li>
    <li>{{5+5}}</li>
    <div ng-view=""></div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The reason they are appearing below is you are rendering those views in list elements ahead of of them. Is it really necessary to render those views in that list? Wouldn't you be better off having your navigation at the top and then render those views under the unordered list completely?